# Evaluating the equivalent resistance

Tags: resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flM6KY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to evaluate the equivalent resistance. For that, I noticed R1, R2 and R3 are parallel connected resistors, which yields

$$\dfrac{1}{R} = \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac{1}{3} = 1 \implies R = 1 \Omega $$

R4 and R5 are also in parallel

$$\dfrac{1}{R} = \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{5}{12} \implies R = \dfrac{12}{5} \Omega$$

Now those groups are in series

$$R_{equiv} = 1+\dfrac {12}5 = \dfrac{17}5$$

I believe that my final answer is wrong. Could you point out where I've gone wrong so far?

Regards

Comment: You need to double-check your schematic. It doesn't make any sense as drawn, and R2 is not in parallel with R1.

Comment: The resistance between the left and right ends of your circuit is 3 Ohm (=R2). Other parts do nothing but take some room. Maybe your schematic should be fixed, as already suspected in another comment.

Comment: Or it's a trick homework question and the cat is now out of the bag.

Comment: My diagram seems okay.